# php variable $page not passed correctly into the URL

Tags: php, apache, variables, centos

I'm trying to install a review&approval server from Kollaborate, it's basically a zip package containing js/php files which needs to be deployed in document root, and then navigate to http://server-ip/install/index.php

But navigating to the next page result in a literally passing the $page variable into the URL instead of something like 1.php -> 2.php and so on.. i get this:
`http//server-ip/install/index.php?page=<?=($page+1)`
resulting in a 'Page not found!' Also a some pagecounter on the webpage is not displaying correctly So it looks like the variable $page into the index.php is not passed to the browser correctly with its real value.
suEXEC is disabled as fast-cgi wrapper, and there are some re-writing rules in the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# Is not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Is an existing php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# rewrite index to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

A short snippet from the navigation function which is done with javascript:
Since this is a piece of software which can be purchased and normally don't need
to be editing by customers i just show it as how they construct it. Kollaborate
support could not help me further other than saying that something is wrong in my installation.

```
<?php
$page_count = 15;
$page = 1;
if (isset($_GET['page'])) $page = $_GET['page'];

if (!file_exists("pages/$page.php")) {
    echo '<h1>Error: Page not found!</h1>
    <a href="index.php?page='.($page+1).'"><button>Next Page</button</a>';
    exit;
}
```

and the navigation step a bit further in the index.php

```
<script>
function nextPage()
{
if (typeof endPage == 'function') {
    var err = endPage();
            if (err && err.length > 0) {
        $('#error').html(err);
        $('#error').show();
        return;
    }
}

$('#error').hide();
    window.location.href = "index.php?page=<?=($page+1)?>";
}
</script>
```

This Kollaborate server requires some sort of LAMPP stack on Ubuntu, but i'm using CENTOS and installed the separate required packages like php/mysql/nodejs/

The configuration of this server goes in 15 steps with each step defined in separate php files(1.php thru 15.php) residing in the pages folder within the install folder.

I had this working once with Centos a year ago, but now can't figure out where to look for... is it a malformed config issue in httpd or php? or nodejs perhaps? All is installed on Centos 6.7 with the latest of everything and based on httpd and php 5.5.3(tried nginx before but yields in the same disappointing result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From first glance it look like short tags might not be turned on in your php config. Using short tags `<?` instead of the long tags `<?php` requires that the `short_open_tag` php ini directive be set. If you create a php script in your application and have it run `phpinfo();` there should be a line that tells you if short tags are off or on. Just search for 'short_open_tag'.

You could also try switching to long tag syntax in `index.php`, so instead of

```
window.location.href = "index.php?page=<?=($page+1)?>";
```

the line would be

```
window.location.href = "index.php?page=<?php echo ($page+1);?>";
```

Comment: Wow i would give you 100+ kudos for this correct answer!! It's amazing on how you grasp this kind of erratic behavior... I certainly never guessed this, and surprisingly the supportdesk of kollaborate either.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to install PHP 5.4, which automatically enables the short echo tag irrespective of the short_open_tag value in PHP.ini.

It's probably a better solution to the problem because it allows you to use short echo tags without enabling the potentially XML-breaking short tags.